# Remove non-english from a string Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, typescript

Hey I'm trying to remove numbers from a string using regex. this is my code so far:

> str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');

this removes everything but letters and numbers, how can I change this regex to also remove digits? tried adding /d with no luck

that's not duplicate- none of the answers I saw worked for me. most of them were adding 0-9,A-Z stuff, nothing like the answers here.

thanks!

Comment: Try `str.replace(/[^\w|\s|\d]/gi, '');`

Comment: Well, `str.replace(/[^\w\s]|\d+/gi, '');`

Comment: What about `str.replace(/[0-9]+/g, '')`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `str.replace(/\d/g, '')`. It works for me.

Comment: str.replace(/[^\w\s]|\d+/gi, ''); Best solution, the rest doesn't work as needed. thanks a lot @Wiktor Stribiżew